Selenium testing: This video file cannot be played (Error Code: 224003)
I am trying to automate web testing in Ruby using the latest Selenium-Webdriver and Firefox Geckodriver, and Ruby based Watir, along with a Firefox Browser (to load the website during testing). I also have Chrome driver to test Chrome browsers. When I load a particular website that has a video embeded, and click play the following happens:

It plays successfully in the app when testing in Chrome.
I get the following error when I test in Firefox: This video file cannot be played (Error Code: 224003)

The video player used on the website is JWPlayer
How can I fix this?

